# how to eal with a column name having comma space or and

Tags: data, sql, databases

I am taking the Coursera assignments on SQL and came across to a question where one of the tables has a column with this name:

**Elementary, Middle, or High School**

I do not know how to deal with this column. However, I saw this answer on the web recommending to refer to  it as this:

```
(Elementary||', '||Middle||', or '||High School)  Elementary, Middle, or High School
```

but I got this error:

```
sqlite:///FinalDB.db
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "School": syntax error
[SQL: select (Elementary||', '||Middle||', or '||High School)  Elementary, Middle, or High School, avg(safety_score) from schools groupby (Elementary||', '||Middle||', or '||High School)  Elementary, Middle, or High School]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Comment: This fits stackoverflow better, I think.

Comment: I think this is caused by the fact that the 'High School' column has a space in its name, you can use double quotes to use the column, i.e. `"High School"`.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Ok, let me check it to see if it works.